# What does 'Definition for strickly-linked list' and does that strictly necessary in Add Two Numbers Problem?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I am having difficulty inputing my program into Leet code. I believe my code is correct, but are these keywords essential:

```
this.val = val;
this.next = null;
```

Q. You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

Example:

```
Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
```

```js
function addTwoNumbers(l1, l2) {
    list1 = l1;
    list2 = l2;
    for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
        let newNum1 = (l1[i] * 100) + (l1[i + 1] * 10) + (l1[i + 2] * 1);
        let newNum2 = (l2[i] * 100) + (l2[i + 1] * 10) + (l2[i + 2] * 1);
        result = newNum1 + newNum2;

        result = Array.from(result.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));
        let newArr = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            newArr.push((Number(result[i])));
        }
        return newArr;
    }
}

console.log(addTwoNumbers([2, 4, 3], [5, 6, 4]));
// [3,4,2] + [4,6,5] = [8,0,7] --> [7,0,8]
```

As you can see, my result is an array of numbers that reflects the reversing of the two arrays, summing them and then reversing them again.

Here is the link to leetcode.com: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

Comment: This is a typical tactic that almost every code challenge employs: to flunk the programmer by describing the problem in an overly obscure fashion. What it really is is a regular expression and string formatting challenge that can be solved without any linked lists whatsoever. Figuring this out is, in fact, a part of the challenge.

Comment: @rm- Do you have any suggestions on how to implement it in my code because i'm not sure how they would fit in?

Comment: `l1` and `l2` are of type `ListNode`.

Comment: The limited enthusiasm for this question may be due to its title: There is a phrase in quotation marks without a hint where it comes from or what it means - who is to tell what it *does*? What *is* your [answerable problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @rm- It doesn't get strings as inputs but actual linked list objects

Comment: @TylerMorales Your code is wrong. It works on arrays, not on lists - and worse it only works on arrays of fixed length. What you actually will get as input is `{val: 2, next: {val: 4, next: {val: 3, next:null}}}`. You are supposed to implement an [add with carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(arithmetic)) algorithm